# Write CSV file using xlsxwriter ByteIO object

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, jira, xlsxwriter

I am creating one .xlsx file using xlsxwriter ByteIO object, Using same object I want to create .CSV file.  is it possible?

Here is my code:

```
outputStr=BytesIO()
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(outputStr,{'in_memory': True})
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Some data we want to write to the worksheet.
row = 0
col = 0
expenses=(['OriginalURL','NormalizedURL','Response','DuplicateOf','SourceId', 'RelatedSources'],)

for OriginalURL,NormalizedURL,Response,DuplicateOf,SourceId,RelatedSources in (expenses):
    worksheet.write(row, col,   OriginalURL)
    worksheet.write(row, col+1, NormalizedURL)
    worksheet.write(row, col+2, Response)
    worksheet.write(row, col+3, DuplicateOf)
    worksheet.write(row, col+4, SourceId)
    worksheet.write(row, col+5, RelatedSources)
    row += 1

workbook.close()
```

Without storing the file, Using "outputStr" object I am attaching the ".xlsx" file in JIRA cloud.

Here is the Jira Code(working with .xlsx file):

```
thisJira.add_attachment(issue=new_issue, attachment=outputStr, filename='Result.xlsx')
```

I want to attach CSV file with same result(Same code I tried with .csv but it not working):

```
thisJira.add_attachment(issue=new_issue, attachment=outputStr, filename='CopyResult.csv')
```

I am getting this error in CSV file:

"The file format and extension of ".xls" don't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open it. Do you want to open it anyway?"

Help me ! Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module to write CSVs alongside your XLSX files, you'll just have to create it a bit differently:

```
import csv
import io
import xslxwriter

xlsx_data = io.BytesIO()
csv_data = io.StringIO()  # on Python 2.x use `io.BytesIO()`

# XLSX part
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(xlsx_data, {'in_memory': True})
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# CSV part
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_data)

# Some data we want to write to the worksheet.
expenses=(['OriginalURL', 'NormalizedURL', 'Response', 'DuplicateOf',
           'SourceId', 'RelatedSources'],)

for row, data in enumerate(expenses):
    # XSLX part
    worksheet.write_row(row, 0, data)  # if needed, add an offset to the row/column

    # CSV part
    csv_writer.writerow(data)

workbook.close()

# CSV data available in csv_data, XLSX data available in xlsx_data
```

It's not clear from your question whether you want to have them both created at the same time or not - if not, just remove the XLSX parts (and you can do `csv_writer.writerows(expenses)` directly, without iterating over individual rows).

Comment: I think you mean `csv_writer.writerow(data)` in the CSV part of the for loop, don't you?